# Sum values of dictionary in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a string column in a SQL database in the format below:

```
{string_one:1;string_two:2;string_three:3}
```

What is the best way to sum up the values in this column so that the output would be just the sum:

```
6
```

I am using postgresql

Comment: A dictionary in sql? Please update this question's tags with the RDBMS you are using (postgres, oracle, sql server, mysql, etc) Is this JSON in a proper JSON type'd field?

Comment: The best way would be to store these 3 values in 3 separate records in an int-column instead of in the same as a string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a string field, then you could use a combination of regexp_replace and regexp_split_to_table.

```
select id, sum(number_values) from (
  select id, 
  regexp_replace(regexp_split_to_table(col_name, ';'), '\D', '','g')::integer as number_values
  from my_table
  )z
group by id
```

The split-to-table will create virtual rows for each "delimited" value in the string, and then we replace non-numbers with nothing. Finally, that is casted to integer type.

DB-fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5bBmpvgtr4AnMp8Hj1bKf2/0).

This works as long as you don't have other numbers in the string that you're trying to remove. If this is a json column, then there are much better solutions. But you didn't mention json as of the time this answer was posted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I really appreciate it. Is there a way to do this in Redshift as well?

Comment: @AlbertCheng Not sure, I'm not familiar with Redshift. But you have postgres tagged, and this answer addresses that tag. If you need to replicate on Redshift, then try looking up similar functions and adapt them. Last resort, if you're still stuck, then open a new question but tag as Redshift. I think this current question has been resolved.